# AsyncTasks loadingImage when i insert data Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would create a imageLoading when I insert some data in my databases. I would use an AsyncTask but it's not work.
The data are loaded by a webservice and after the response of my webservice I insert the data.

So i have my Activity with my AsyncTask :

```
     private void synchronisationContact() {
        NetworkInfo network = ((ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (network==null || !network.isConnected())
        {
          // Le périphérique n'est pas connecté à Internet
          Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, Constants.ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERNET_SYNC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
          // Le périphérique est connecté à Internet
          Configuration configuration = configurationService.getConfiguration();
          if(configuration == null) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, Constants.ERROR_NO_CONFIGURATION, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            String numeroToken = configuration.getNumeroToken();
            Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this,"Synchronisation lancée", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            synchronisationService.appelImportWebService(numeroToken, ContactsActivity.this);
          }
        }
  }

  public void displayWebserviceCallResponse(String message) {
    if(message == Constants.SUCCES) {
      Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      findViewById(R.id.imageLoading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (message == Constants.ERROR_TOKEN || message == Constants.ERROR_CHAMPS_URL){
      Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Intent secondeActivite = new Intent(ContactsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
      startActivity(secondeActivite);
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(ContactsActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      findViewById(R.id.imageLoading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }

  private void listenerButtonHistorique() {
    imageButtonHistorique.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent secondeActivite = new Intent(ContactsActivity.this, HistoriqueActivity.class);
        startActivity(secondeActivite);
      }

    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_synchro:
        ImportData importData = new ImportData();
        importData.execute();
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }

  private class ImportData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      synchronisationContact();
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And i have a service where i insert data and i make the call of my webservice :

```
private class WebserviceCall extends Thread {

    private final String numeroToken;
    private final String url;

    private ContactsActivity activity;

    private String message = null;

    public WebserviceCall(String numeroToken, String url) {
      this.numeroToken = numeroToken;
      this.url = url;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
      return message;
    }

    public void setActivity(ContactsActivity activity) {
      this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Log.d("SynchronisationContactsServiceImpl","Appel webService contacts import");
      String urlwebService = url + Constants.BASE_URL_SYNC;
      final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();
      Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(urlwebService)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

      CfirstWebService service = retrofit.create(CfirstWebService.class);
      Call<ImportJSON> call = service.importContacts(numeroToken);
      call.enqueue(new Callback<ImportJSON>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ImportJSON> call, Response<ImportJSON> response) {
          if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            responseImport = response.body();
            suppressionContactsBdd();
            insertionDonneesBdd(responseImport);
            message = Constants.SUCCES;
            updateMessage(message);
          } else {
            int code = response.code();
            if(code==403) {
              message = Constants.ERROR_AUTORIZATION;
              updateMessage(message);
              Log.d(TAG, Constants.ERROR_AUTORIZATION);
            } else if (code==401) {
              suppressionContactsBdd();
              message = Constants.ERROR_TOKEN;
              updateMessage(message);
              Log.d(TAG, Constants.ERROR_TOKEN);
            } else if (code==404) {
              message = Constants.ERROR_CHAMPS_URL;
              updateMessage(message);
              Log.d(TAG, Constants.ERROR_CHAMPS_URL);
            }
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ImportJSON> call, Throwable t) {
          t.printStackTrace();
          message = Constants.FAIL;
        }
      });
    }

    private void updateMessage(final String message) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          activity.displayWebserviceCallResponse(message);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  public String appelImportWebService(final String numeroToken, ContactsActivity contactsActivity) {
    configurationDAO.open();
    Configuration configBDD = configurationDAO.getConfiguration();
    final String url = configBDD.getUrl();
    configurationDAO.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "Debut appel synchronisation contacts web service");
    WebserviceCall thread = new WebserviceCall(numeroToken, url);
    thread.setActivity(contactsActivity);
    thread.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "Fin appel synchronisation contacts web service");
    return thread.getMessage();
  }

  public void insertionDonneesBdd(ImportJSON importJSON) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Debut insertion des contacts dans la bdd local");
    List<ContactJSON> listeContacts = importJSON.getListeContactsJson();
    List<InterlocuteurJSON> listeInterlocuteurs = importJSON.getListeInterlocuteurs();

    List<ContactJSON> listeInsertionContacts = new ArrayList<ContactJSON>();
    List<InterlocuteurJSON> listeInsertionInterlocuteurs = new ArrayList<InterlocuteurJSON>();

    int count = 0;

    if (listeContacts != null && listeContacts.size() != 0) {
      Iterator c = listeContacts.iterator();
      while (c.hasNext()) {
        ContactJSON contactJSON = (ContactJSON) c.next();
        Log.d(TAG, "Insertion contacts: "+ contactJSON.getNom());
        listeInsertionContacts.add(contactJSON);
        if (count == 1000) {
          insertionContacts(listeInsertionContacts);
          listeInsertionContacts.clear();
          count = 0;
        } else {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }

    if (listeInterlocuteurs != null && listeInterlocuteurs.size() != 0) {
      count = 0;
      Iterator i = listeInterlocuteurs.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
        InterlocuteurJSON interlocuteurJSON = (InterlocuteurJSON) i.next();
        Log.d(TAG, "Insertion interlocuteurs: "+ interlocuteurJSON.getNomPrenom());
        listeInsertionInterlocuteurs.add(interlocuteurJSON);
        if (count == 1000) {
          insertionInterlocuteurs(listeInsertionInterlocuteurs);
          listeInsertionInterlocuteurs.clear();
          count = 0;
        } else {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    interlocuteurDAO.close();
    contactDAO.close();
    imageDAO.close();
    telephoneDAO.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "Fin insertion des contacts dans la bdd local");
  }
```

The image work when I load the data of webservice, but when I insert in the database (with the function : insertionDonneesBdd(responseImport); )  it's not work.